# Javascript DOM ready without an entire framework

Tags: javascript, domready

Does anyone know of a good javascript DOM ready library that I can use without loading an entire framework?  I found one on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/domready/) that seems to work, but the library was posted in 2008 and I can't find any confirmation on up-to-date cross browser support.

Comment: have you taken a look at http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/ ? Specifically [this comment](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/#comment367184). Its not plug'n'play ready...but it shouldn't be too hard to set up.

Comment: I'd have to ask why is the only thing - jQuery is 19k zipped, and loaded once, used by millions of people on a daily basis so you know it has to work.

Comment: Im with altcognito, look into jQuery is your best bet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the safest bet is indeed to use a javascript framework.  I was able to find some small DOMready libraries - but nothing written recently or claiming to be confirmed working with the most current browser releases.

Answer (score 9):

David Mark's "My Library" has a "DOM ready" functionality:

http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html

David is avid anti-framework, anti-bad-javascript-practice so it should be good quality code.

Comment: Also his library is completely modular so you can just use the DOM ready part without having to get "everything".

Comment: The very minimal core  + domready extension are 8K uncompressed and unminified.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this right before the closing body tag:

```
<html>
<script>
function runAfterLoad() {
}
... lots of stuff
</script>
<body>

... lots of stuff

<script>runAfterLoad();</script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Dean Edwards' [base2](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2007/12/base2-intro/). It contains a minimal amount of code necessary to patch up browser differences and provide nice consistent interface as per the standards. The gzipped version is only 6k.

Answer (score 1):

Use ded's [domready](https://github.com/ded/domready)

Answer (score 0):

please check out this simple function [dom ready function](https://gist.github.com/yehiaa/c859dceb135d61d9583a)

it has been tested in ie 8 , firefox, chrome and safari .

and check this answer [javascript domready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready/18193502#18193502)