# Call a HTML element from a separate Javascript File (Getting error: "can't find variable document")

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just trying to get an element from the html file that I'm using in conjunction with my JS file, but I'm running into a ReferenceError of "Can't find variable: document".

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
var m = document.getElementById("metric");
```

The javascript file is called in the HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Why isn't "document." working??

Any help would be appreciated! For the record, I'm working in vanilla javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: It appears this isn't possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118971/is-window-document-ever-null-or-undefined

My guess is you don't have a valid html document

Comment: Can you show your JS and HTML?

Comment: @Teemu If it were an argument name, why would it say the variable isn't found?

Comment: It doesn't matter what value is passed. If it's a parameter, the variable exists, it just doesn't have a value.

Comment: I suspect you have a typo in `document`.