# window.location.href window is not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, mailto

I am trying to send an automatic reply to who uses my contact form using jquery and javascript. The function I have implemented is this

```
    function sendReply(email,Name)
{
        var linker = "mailto:"+email
             + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("automated Reply")
             + "&body=Hello "+Name+" Thank you for your e-mail. we will contact you soon.";

        window.location.href=linker;
}
```

I am using nodeJs. The error message points to `window` and says reference error window is not defined.

Extra information : When a user clicks the send mail button it will route to a page where a jquery is implemented which will do some function there and if and only if it was successful, im trying to send this above mentioned reply.
That is like this,

```
        success: function(message) 
     {

      sendReply(req.body.email,req.body.name);
      res.send(304, '/#contact');  

     }
```

I've debugged and checks. It passes the parameters correctly and it runs up to the `window.location.href=linker;` point.
I've gone through tons of pages and spent hours to find out what is wrong.
I am not an expert in javascript and jquery so if you could point me out my error and the solution, that will be a great help. Thank you.

Comment: You can't use the `window` object on the server (nodeJS). This is a purely browser artifact.

Comment: Server side node.js indeed has no `window` instance. You must put that line in the client side code that calls the server side code.

Comment: what can I use here instead of windows?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118971/is-window-document-ever-null-or-undefined

Comment: Nothing. The server can't directly interact with the browser, only send responses that the browser can then handle.

Answer (score 0):

is it work?

```
function sendReply(email,Name,res)
{
            var linker = "mailto:"+email
                 + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
                 + "&subject=" + escape("automated Reply")
                 + "&body=Hello "+Name+" Thank you for your e-mail. we will contact you soon.";

            //window.location.href=linker;


            res.writeHead(301,
                         {Location: linker}
                         );
            res.end();
}
```