# How do I run Javascript on Document Ready in Google Optimize?

Tags: google-optimize

How do I run javascript on window load or document ready in Google Optimize campaigns? It seems like it allows me to select DOM elements all the way up to Body, but I need to run js on document ready.

Answer (score 16):

This is the way I go about it:

1. Edit your experiment variant in the Visual Editor.
2. Click on the *Select elements* icon (the rectangle in the top left corner)
3. In the *Element Selector* field, type in `body`.
4. Click the *Add change* button and select Javascript. This will bring up a dialog that allows you to input a JS function that will be called for the body.
5. Put in the code you want to run in there and make sure the *After closing tag* option is selected.

Because of the nature of Google Optimize, I would expect that it wouldn't start messing around with DOM elements until they are loaded. And because you select the *After closing tag* option on the body tag that should ensure all elements have been loaded in the DOM.

However, if you want to be 100% sure, you could write a function like this.

```
function runOnLoad() {
    console.log('this will only run when window is loaded');
}
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
    runOnLoad();
} else {
    window.addEventListener("onload", runOnLoad, false);
}
```

That code snippet was adapted from [How to check if DOM is ready without a framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100576/how-to-check-if-dom-is-ready-without-a-framework)

Comment: "In the Element Selector field, type in body." does not allow me to select the body element.

Comment: @FullDecent I tried it again just now and it's still seems to be working for me. You can't use the point-and-click GUI to select the body. You need to click square icon and manually type in the word "body". 

Alternatively, you could try selecting a different element and apply the JS to that one. In theory, it should work, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Ok, correction. I could type `body` and see "Elements: 1". But I could not click ADD CHANGE because of the insufficiently-documented rule that you cannot add changes while an experiment is running.

Answer (score 2):

if the above code doesn't work.

Try to use:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(document .readyState === "complete") {
      console.log('this will only run when window is loaded');
    }
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState