# Google Optimize - create A/B test with dynamic URL

Tags: google-optimize

i'm from business and I would like to ask is it possible to create A/B test with dynamic part of URL?

API of backend application returns calculation ID for every visitor and its included on URL.

For example:
We have main URL www.example.pl and I want to create A/B test with redirect to dynamic URL:
www.example.com/calculation/(calculculation_id)

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please clarify, what is the base url, and what would be the redirect url? Could you extend your example url with this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The base URL is www.example.com/mortgage/static and redirect URL is www.example.com/calculation/11111, where "11111" is dynamic and get new number for every web visitor. When I want to redirect to URL I can't write static URL.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to redirect from https://www.example.com/product/laptop/12345
to https://www.example.com/product/laptop-test/12345  for each product and not for the product 12345.

0. **Select test type redirect**
1. **Set up redirect rules for each variant**
2. **Customize your page targeting rules with "contains" or "starts with."**
3. **Customize your advanced redirection"**

**1.Set up redirect rules for each variant**

Find in domain/path com/product
Replace with    com/product-test

Add/modify query parameters/fragments   (leave blank)

Original:   https://www.example.com/product/laptop/12345

Redirect:   https://www.example.com/product-test/laptop/12345 (see point  3.Customize your advanced redirection)

! Do not worry if you are entering the specific product 12345 this value seen by the system as variable xxxxx !

**2.Customize your page targeting rules with "contains" or "starts with."**

Modify the page targeting rules to ensure that we include any URL containing example.com/product.

**3.Customize your  advanced redirection.**

In our example the text "com/product" is replaced with  "com/product-test".

[image]

This is the site where you can find more information :
https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6361119?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in different ways. I'd suggest using [Feature Flags](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) approach in your A/B test in order to have a flag to generated the dynamic next URL from the API.

I'll try to summarize in two steps that you should go:

1. Add a Javascript in the Optimize Visual Editor for. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455435/how-do-i-run-javascript-on-document-ready-in-google-optimize). The idea is this script to add a new flag:

```
    window.FeatureManager = window.FeatureManager || {};
    window.FeatureManager.variant_1_to_change_the_url = true;
```

[image]

2. On your own script, look at this flag to call the backend API in order to get the calculated URL:

```
    // in case of the variant 1
    if (window.FeatureManager && window.FeatureManager.variant_1_to_change_the_url) {
      // calls the API passing this flag to get the new URL
      const redirectURL = fetch('my_endpoint', true/false); // true/false could be the variant verification
      location.href = redirectURL; // this is a sample, you can change the URL however you want
    } else {
        // the original variation
    }
```