# How to get role="presentation" elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to get an element and modify it.

It looks like in the developer console;

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]').forEach(function(el) {
  console.log('test');
  console.log('innerHTML: ' + el.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="toolBarId">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr role="presentation">someElements1</tr>
      <tr>someElements2</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

if I write;

```
document.getElementById('toolBarId').innerHTML;
```

It prints;

```
someElements2
```

I tried;

```
document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]').forEach(function (el){
         console.log('test');
//       console.log('innerHTML: ' + el.innerHTML);
         });
```

It prints nothing.

Edit:
I added this just before "/body" in the base html. Did not work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

         document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]').forEach(function (el){
             console.log('test');
//           console.log('innerHTML: ' + el.innerHTML);
             });
         </script>
</body>
```

Edit2:

```
    if(document.readyState === "complete") {
        testPresentation() ;
        // seems never called
    }
    else {
          window.addEventListener("onload", function () 
                  {testPresentation() ;}, false);
            // seems never called

          //or
          document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {testPresentation() ;}, false);
            // called but selector cannot find first row of the table still
    }

function testPresentation() {

    console.log('testPresentation called');

         document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]').forEach(function (el){
             console.log('test');
//           console.log('innerHTML: ' + el.innerHTML);
             });
}
```

Comment: It seems to work as expected https://jsbin.com/waremupefa/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Then what would be the problem? Maybe js code that generates table runs after my queryselector? But then I would'nt get second row also.

Comment: From what the first statement prints, it looks like the first row is not there (the one with the `role` attribute) when that statement runs. It looks like the `#toolBarId` div doesn't contain a table, it has just this text: `someElements2`

Comment: Can i arrange some priority that queryselector would be the code runs finally? Thanks

Comment: Yes, call that after the function that generates the table is done.

Comment: Actually the line I include my js file is the last line in the head section. The other javascript events runs behind the scene by the framework (wicket), I couldnt find a way of order yet.

Comment: What if you run the selector [only after DOM is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100576/how-to-check-if-dom-is-ready-without-a-framework)?

Answer (score 1):

**Your table HTML is invalid.**

`tr` elements cannot have `TextNode` children. The only allowed children are `td` and `th` elements (and `script` and `template`). If you fix that, it works as expected:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]').forEach(function(el) {
  console.log('innerHTML: ' + el.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="toolBarId">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td role="presentation">someElements1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>someElements2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

> ### table-row `<tr>`
>
> Permitted content:  Zero or more `<td>` and/or `<th>` elements; script-supporting elements (`<script>` and `<template>`) are also allowed
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

Comment: tr element has td's in it

Comment: @classeswilldullyourmind Not in the HTML you've shown in the question.