# How do I add a US dollar sign to currency numbers on a webpage using a userscript?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to add a `$` sign to multiple currency values on a webpage that does not contain currency symbols.

For example, I would like `25.00` to be formatted as `$25.00`. Another example is that I would like `3,100.00` to be formatted as `$3,100.00`.

I am currently using a userscript in the Violentmonkey browser extension to accomplish this task. For some unknown reason, my current userscript is not formatting the numbers on the webpage.

I tried using a regular expression to hopefully fix the issue, but the numbers remain unformatted despite executing my userscript.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function checkReadyState() {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete' || document.readyState === 'interactive') {
            // Regex to find numbers with two decimal places (with or without commas)
            const numberRegex = /\d+(,\d+)*\.\d\d/;

            // Find all text nodes (more general than specific elements)
            const textNodes = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
            let currentNode;

            // Function from StackOverflow
            const money = (amount, currency = 'USD', locale = 'en-US') => {
                return Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
                    style: 'currency',
                    currency
                }).format(amount);
            }

            while (currentNode = textNodes.nextNode()) {
                const text = currentNode.nodeValue;
                const modifiedText = text.replace(numberRegex, (match) => {
                    // Don't add '$' if it already exists
                    if (match.startsWith('$')) {
                        return match;
                    } else {
                        const amount = parseFloat(match.replace(/,/g, '')); // Remove commas
                        return money(amount);
                    }
                });
                if (modifiedText !== text) {
                    const newNode = document.createTextNode(modifiedText);
                    currentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, currentNode);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Wait for the document to be ready
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkReadyState);
        }
    }

    // Call the function initially
    checkReadyState();
})();
```

```
    <p>25.00</p>

    <p>3,100.00</p>

    <div data-cellname="[object Object]" class="css-12hdbj5 css-nil">3,105.00</div>
    <br>

    <span data-testid="__global!balance-1a1d49c3-9cb8-4c67-896c-0122ac627f08" data-cellname="__global!balance-1a1d49c3-9cb8-4c67-896c-0122ac627f08" class=" css-1ai95jy">45.14</span>
    <br>

<span class=" css-bs1bqe">90.00</span>
    <br>
```

Comment: I edited your code in to an executable snippet where it works absolutely fine. If it's not working for you then we need more details about your implementation - ideally with the HTML you're running it on included. It's possible that the content you're attempting to update isn't ready when the DOM loads, or the userscript is being run too early in the page lifecycle, or an error somewhere else in the page. Given the limited information we're current;y unable to debug the problem.

Comment: Here is some example HTML code that I am trying to target with the userscript. `<div data-cellname="[object Object]" class="css-12hdbj5 css-nil">0.00</div>`,  `<span data-testid="__global!balance-1a1d49c3-9cb8-4c67-896c-0122ac627f08" data-cellname="__global!balance-1a1d49c3-9cb8-4c67-896c-0122ac627f08" class=" css-1ai95jy">45.14</span>`, and `<span class=" css-bs1bqe">0.00</span>`. I hope that helps.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, `Intl` object offers an excellent util methods such as currency formatting (see [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)) if you're targeting evergreen browsers. Can you access the source data directly instead of scraping from HTML markup? If so, it'll make it much easier to format it as number, rather than using RegEx on strings.

Comment: I need to scrape information from the HTML markup and then update the HTML to include the `$`. I am using a modern evergreen (auto-updating) web browser.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has an `Intl` object that exposes the `NumberFormat` method. With this method, you can create a function that should accept the money to be formatted to $.

```
const money = (amount, currency = 'USD', locale = 'en-US') => {
    return Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
        style: 'currency',
        currency
    }).format(amount);
}
```

You can give the function any name of your choice.

Now, to format the number to $, simply call the function passing the number to it:

```
let number = 25;
console.log(money(25));
// $25.00
```

For more, checkout the docs at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

Comment: I incorporated the code you suggested in my userscript, but when I run the userscript JavaScript code, the numbers remain without the `$`.

Comment: @MichaelGunter, you're using an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). If your script is loading before the DOM, then it won't working because there's DOM interaction in your code. You can try loading the DOM first, maybe using defer or placing the script towards the end of the closing body tag.

Comment: @MichaelGunter The code above works as stated/shown, outputting the value of `money(20)` as a string `"$20.00"`. This should help you debug the issue in your code.

Comment: @MichaelGunter You can check for `document.readyState` being equal to `"complete"` or `"interactive"` before running your script, per Emmanuel's comment! See this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8100952

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that suggestion, but the changes are still not taking effect.