# Load javascript before Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload

In this page: http://www.depositosalto.com.br/lojas.php, I have a javascript to resize a div and a iframe containing a google maps location. Happens that the javascript is executed only after the iframe is loaded. How I do to the javascript be executed first?

EDIT: The javascript is not to resize the iframe, but another div with the content with id = "conteudo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the proper size of the IFRAME and then generate the IFRAME tag using JavaScript. This will guarantee that your IFRAME will appear only after JS code executed.

P.S. Use  tag to make sure that people who has JavaScript turned off will still see the IFRAME with Google Map.

Comment: The script is not to resize the iframe, but another div in the page.

Comment: It actually does not matter (DIV of IFRAME) you can still generate it using JS and perform calculation of the size prior to that.

Comment: I using this solution now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<body onload: >` option. This triggers when the page is first loaded.

Comment: You can see some non library dependent code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready

Comment: Currently I using body onload.