# script tag inside body and behavior of appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, browser, standards

I'm curious what "should" happen in the example below.  Most current browsers (Firefox 5, Chrome 14, Opera 11.50) will add the `iframe` above the text but is it a standardised behaviour or just a common way of doing things that could change in the future?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Will the iframe be above or below the text?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var e = document.createElement("iframe");
      document.body.appendChild(e);
    </script>
    <p>some text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standardised behaviour.

When script runs there are yet no children in body.

Comment: Do you know what standard says that scripts have to be executed when encountered and execution can't be delayed until for example DOM is ready?

Comment: @maarons, I don't know exactly what the standard says. But my experience says that you can delay execution only by putting script right before "</body>" or using [domready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready)

Comment: See <http://www.whatwg.org/html>. More relevantly, roughly every script on the web relies (knowingly or unknowingly) on this behaviour.

Comment: Molecule I'm aware how it is interpreted in most browsers but I wanted to know if there is any standard behind this behaviour. @Ms2ger Still there are browsers with different behaviour - Opera Mobile would be one of them, so not every browser does that.

Comment: @Ms2ger Thanks for the link, found this: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#script and then this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.4 It says that scripts have to be executed immediately when encountered.

Comment: Mm, Opera Mobile is a special case, not sure what it does. I'd suggest not relying on HTML4 for.. Well, anything really. It's known to be incomplete or incorrect in almost everything it says.

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/En/AppendChild

> Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.

As @Molecule points out, the script is executed while the tree is not yet constructed, so this node is appended on an empty list, so ends up being the first element. It's probably implementation-specific though.

Comment: As Molecule points out `body` doesn't have children when script is encountered so still not sure what should happen.

Comment: Yep, this makes sense since the tree is not built yet. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

That script will be executed first and then the HTML element `<p>`, so that's why you get the iframe first. If you want to have the iframe at the bottom, put your script at the bottom as well. So yes, it's a standard thing.

Comment: Seems to directly contradict with kbok's answer.  Does the browser "have" to run the script when it encounters it (can't delay the execution until DOM is ready)?  At least Opera Mobile waits and will add the `iframe` at the bottom.

Comment: it seems, but your script is not contained in any functions or event handlers which is waiting for a call. It's just there so the browser will directly execute it when it is found.

Comment: You are right, that's the point.  Are browsers required to run the script when it is found (and body has no children) or can (maybe even should?) wait until body tag is closed and then execute the code?

Comment: yes, as soon as the browser found your "direct" script like that, it will execute it directly. That's why if you need to interact with other elements, you should place your "direct" script at the bottom, unless you're using window.onload or any other function which is called when the document is fully loaded.

Comment: by "direct" i mean a script not contained in a function or event handlers that it waits for a call.

Answer (score 0):

You can only manipulate DOM tree when it gets ready. Therefore, you need to write the code in window's onload event (any browser) or DOMContentLoaded event (Non-IE).

```
window.onload = function() {
    var e = document.createElement("iframe");
    document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

Comment: That isn't true. You can manipulate an element as soon as it exists in the DOM (which is when the start tag is parsed). (Although this can cause MSIE to throw obscure error messages and blank the page)