# Catch all images while page is loading

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to catch all images while the page is loading, before `onload` is triggered?

I would like to load all images after onload event with some ajax icon on background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready

might work for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute arbitrary Javascript code in the page, without using the `onload` event: (see http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/147703-there-any-call-before-body-onload)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>alert(0)</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="alert(2)">
        ... (content) ...
        <script>alert(1)</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

<sub>(Alert order: 0, 1, 2.)</sub>

Now, at the point of `alert(1)`, you can use [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName), and select your `img` tags to do whatever you want with them. It's even possible to create a script that postpones loading of images until they should be in the visible scroll area. This is useful for huge lists with images.

However, a more easy solution would be to use CSS and apply a background-image on each `img` element.

Comment: Yea i know this tehnique, it's called lazy load. At what stage it's possible to do this "postpones loading of images" ? Thanks ;) As i understand images are rendered after DOM ready event?

Comment: DOM ready is called when the complete page (including images) is rendered. (see http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: When i'm trying to remove images from stack document.getElementsByTagName('img') , half of them is undefined. I'm trying it at the bottom of the document, right before </body> that's why i'm asking

Answer (score 0):

Consider using transition elements, that can be replaced onload.

```
 <a rel="image" href="path/to/img"><img src="loader.gif"></a>
```

Like embedding flash.

Comment: this would best be implemented in a template ... if you can't go with Pindatjuh's answer