# "listen " wait for tag to print

Tags: javascript

I have javascript "API" function that need a certain tag to work with.

i got problem with the positioning of the script. here is what i mean :

1. if the Script has been written in the head , i need to wait for the tag to get printed to work with , what's means that i need to follow on the page and check when the tag get print and than start the function.
2. if the script has been written in the body after the tag got printed , i can't call the function after the tag got printed , like this :

`<tag></tag> <script> startfunction(); </script>`

my question is , how can i follow the tag , check if it prints , if it does start the functions , if it doesn't "listen" to the tag and wait for it to print and than start the function , *i cant wait for the whole page to load.

how to make it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you wait for the document to finish loading? The easiest way, would be to listen for the "load" event on your window element, and trigger your code then...

I don't know if you're using some JS library like jQuery, Prototype or something else...

Here is some standard JS for handling this type of event:

```
if( window.addEventListener ) {
  window.addEventListener('load',handlerFunction,false);
} else if( document.addEventListener ) {
  document.addEventListener('load',handlerFunction,false);
}
```

Your handlerFunction would trigger all necessary functions, you could then do something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tag")
```

And check if that code returns any elements in order to know if your tag got printed...

Does this help? Let me know.

**Edit**
BTW, this could be a duplicate of: [javascript domready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready)

Comment: on the picee of code you gave , i need to change the 'window' to my tag?

Comment: Nope, on that code, you're waiting for the DOM to finish loading, that means your tag also..., that's the best way to check....

Comment: wow , that's great. that's similar to the jquery document.ready ?

Comment: another question , is that fully supported by all browsers?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be, I'd recommend checking out the link I added, it talks a bit more about browser compatibiliy. Also, if you're using jquery, you can safely use document.ready , since it's the same thing...