# In JQuery, how do I check if the DOM is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript domready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready)

I want to check whether `$(function(){ });` is "ready".

Return true if DOM is ready, false otherwise

Comment: Rephrase, please?  I'm not quite understanding what you want.  The DOM is ready right before the callback (in your example, the `function() {}`) runs.

Comment: People (including the jQuery API docs) call it the "document ready function". ;-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From jQuery code

```
if ( jQuery.isReady ) {  
    fn.call( document, jQuery );
}
```

Comment: Just making a comment here that this is not a documented property and  the authors of jQuery could change/remove this property at any time without notice.  Use at your own risk and be careful when updating jQuery.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the explicit call

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // do this after dom is ready
});
```

Or use the shortcut

```
$(function(){
  // do this after dom is ready
});
```

It's also useful to wrap your jQuery in an anonymous function when you're using other libraries; Also very common to use this when writing jQuery plugins.

```
(function($, window){
  // use $ here freely if you think any other library might have overridden it outside.
  $(function(){
    // do this after dom is ready
  });
})(jQuery, window);
```

Lastly, you can use `jQuery.isReady` (bool)

```
if (jQuery.isReady) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: You can also do `jQuery(function($) { /* jQuery is aliased to $ inside this block even if another library is normally assigned to $ */ });`

Answer (score 2):

That function will only execute when the dom is ready.  That's the point of wrapping your code in that function ;).  Having said that, some things (like images, deferred scripts, etc.) might not be fully loaded or rendered yet, so be aware.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.isReady`, but it's undocumented and should be avoided.

If you just need to run something after the DOM is ready, you can just call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

as normal – that will run the code immediately if the DOM is ready and wait until it is if not.