# How can I check execute some javascript after my DOM is loaded and after another js has finished loading?

Tags: javascript

I am using the javascript [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js)   Once my page is loaded it says that should execute the script as below:

Placeholders.init({
    live: true, //Apply to future and modified elements too
    hideOnFocus: true //Hide the placeholder when the element receives focus
});

I am NOT using jQuery. How can I know when to execute the init because it depends on two things: The Placeholders.js script having loaded and my form fields having loaded.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207005/464744?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know when to execute the init because it depends on two things: The Placeholders.js script having loaded and my form fields having loaded.

Put the `script` tag doing the `Placeholders.init` call at the bottom of the document, just before your closing `</body>` tag. All of the elements above it are accessible at that point.

Example:

```
<body>
  <input id="theField" value="value from HTML" type="text">
  <script>
    document.getElementById("theField").value =
      "value from JavaScript";
  </script>
</body>
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ufamam/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ufamam/1/edit)

The result is that the field has the text `"value from JavaScript"`. Reliably, cross-browser.

References:

- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google Closure Library engineers on when DOM elements are ready](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E/RjllWWJTXAcJ)

Answer (score -1):

You can check it like this:

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    // insert your code here
}
```

The enclosed in the 'if' statement above will not run until the document has been fully loaded. In jQuery you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // insert code here });
```