# CSS3 Run Page Transition When Html Rendered

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css, css-transitions

I have a simple `CSS3` fade in page transition, which works well (*ONLY care about IE10+*). Here's what it looks like:

**HEAD**

```
body
{
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 1s ease;
}

.loaded
{
   opacity:1;
}
```

**BODY**

```
<body onload="document.body.classList.add('loaded');">
```

The only problem now, is that if the page has a lot of images, the onload event is triggered only when all of them are downloaded.

What can I do, using pure javascript or CSS to do the fade in, even while images are downloading?

**NOTE: Can't use any external js files or frameworks.**

Comment: You need to do the onDomReady: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only care about IE10+ (and other major browsers I assume), you can use the HTML5 event [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
         document.body.classList.add('loaded');
    }, false);
```

This is supported in Chrome 0.2+, FF 1.7+, IE 9+, Opera 9+ and Safari 3.1+.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pure CSS

```
@keyframes fadein {
   0%   { opacity: 0; }
   100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.element-to-fade-in
{
   opacity:1;
   animation: fadein 1s;
}
```

Don't forget to add the prefixes