# Windows Phone WebBrowser: right way to get document height

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, internet-explorer-10

in my Windows Phone 8 app I have a WebBrowser control (Internet Explorer 10). I need to get the total height of the document loaded into it.

I must use only Javascript (no jQuery), so I now I'm using this code (extracted from the jQuery source):

```
documentHeight = Math.max(
            document.body['scrollHeight'],
            document.documentElement['scrollHeight'],
            document.body['offsetHeight'],
            document.documentElement['offsetHeight'],
            document.documentElement['clientHeight']
        );
```

With a long page, I get, for example, `6000 pixels`. To check if the result is correct, I manually scroll to the bottom of the page and I get the `document.documentElement.scrollTop` value.

In this case the value returned is `11000 pixels`, which should be the right value of the document height.

So why the documentHeight is nearly the half of the real value?

Thank you all

Comment: Are you checking the document height after the DOM Ready event?

Comment: No, and that was the problem. I realised that yesterday after submitting the question. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: You can put that as the answer, and make it as 'accepted' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I was trying to get the height of the document *before* the DOM ready event and for this reason the value was wrong.

One of the possible solutions to know when the DOM is loaded is described here: "[javascript domready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready)"