# document.getElementById returns null if alert is removed

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function which gets the object using `document.getElementById`.

```
function updateQuestPartElemement(obj){
  var objid = obj.id;
  var quesids = objid.split("$|$");         
  var qplabelid = quesids[0] + '$|$' + quesids[1] + '$|$' + 'questionPartLabel';    
  alert(qplabelid); //removing this alert, the below object is coming as null
  var qpartlabel = document.getElementById(qplabelid);
  alert(qpartlabel);
}
```

The issue is I dont need the alert for `qplabelid`. But if I remove this alert, `document.getElementById(qplabelid)` is not returning any object. I am confused. Please suggest me something to get the object.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the function after the DOM is ready? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207005/444991

Comment: Try to move your script just in front of your closing `</body>` tag

Comment: Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Thank you.. It worked I have added setTimeout to call my function little later...