# How to fix "TypeError: domPage is undefined" in ViewerJS

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I use the latest version of [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/) to render and show a PDF file on my web application.

For most PDF files, a PDF file is displayed correctly, however for some large PDF files, nothing is shown in a ViewerJS frame.

I checked JapaScript console, then I found an error "`TypeError: domPage is undefined. (PDFViewerPlugin.js line 128)`".

The source code is available [here](https://github.com/kogmbh/ViewerJS/blob/master/PDFViewerPlugin.js)

Do you have any suggestion to fix this problem?

Comment: Wait until the [DOM is Ready](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207005/532978).

Comment: how can I wait for in JavaScript?

Comment: I linked you to an answer that tells you how. If you need more help either comment there or edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not notice the link.