# How to guarantee the jQuery $ is initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In another question, StackOverflow suggested that it's impossible to guarantee the order in which a browser will process `<script>` tags, regardless of their position in the `<head>` or `<body>` (see comments):

[Scripts loading out of order in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785887/scripts-loading-out-of-order-in-chrome)

The top answer recommends using a pure-javascript "DOM-loaded" to guarantee that all dependencies are loaded, then running page-specific code.

This made me wonder whether it's safe to use jQuery's recommended $ function as a substitute for the pure-JS DOM-loaded:

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Src: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

How can I guarantee jQuery's $ will be defined?

EDIT: Examples of hypothetical failure were requested.  Here's one with the external `<script>` in `<body>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
    $(function(){
      alert("Loaded.");
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And one with the external `<script>` in `<head>`...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example 1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      alert("Loaded.");
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Based on [Scripts loading out of order in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785887/scripts-loading-out-of-order-in-chrome), either of these may fail.

Comment: Scripts are loaded in the order they are encountered, unless you've set defer or async, so it's not an issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false this question is very similar to yours, and has very good answers

Comment: @adeneo That is apparently not correct.  Please see "Scripts loading out of order in Chrome" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785887/scripts-loading-out-of-order-in-chrome

Comment: @Colin Can include example of application ?

Comment: @Colin - something else must be going on, billions of websites and users relies on the fact that scripts load in order every single day.

Comment: @adeneo Yea that's why I'm so confused about the other question. Perhaps it's a bug in Chrome?  Or somehow StripeCheckout.js is signaling Chrome to continue despite the whole file not being processed?

Comment: How would a browser react in the extreme case that jQuery is not in cache and downloaded extremely slowly, just fast enough to prevent a timeout?  Would all browsers wait for the script to be loaded?  Would the version of Chrome referenced in the linked question do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you later state it is based on a faulty premise.

Answer (score 1):

This question is based on a faulty premise.  The referenced question, [Scripts loading out of order in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785887/scripts-loading-out-of-order-in-chrome), was for an application using TurboLinks, which effectively turns a static site into a single-page app.  As a result, my `<script>` tags were inserted dynamically, and there was not a guarantee they would be run in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly check if jQuery is loaded until it is, at which point you run some code.

```
<script>
function doStuff() {
   //do jQuery stuff
}

function checkLoaded() {
   if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
      setTimeout(function() {
         checkLoaded();
      }, 50);
   } else {
      doStuff();
   }
}

checkLoaded();
</script>
```