# jQuery in two external java script files

Tags: jquery

I have an html page with 2 external javascript files

one that is global

```
<script src=".../js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and one that is local

```
<script src="js/local.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Obviously, I use jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So far, so good.

In both external javascript files, I insert my jQuery code inside the following piece of code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code goes here...
});
```

I've tried removing that piece of code in the local external javascript file since I've already have it on my global file. But it doesn't work.
So, my question is do i **absolutely** need to start both external java script files with that piece of code? How do i make it so i only have it on my global file?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript domready?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready)

Comment: errors from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 javascript files, and you're doing DOM manipulation in both files (using jQuery) - yes, you need to start both with `$(document).ready(function(){...});`.

Here's what's happening....

```
|- browser requests page from server
|
|- page has <script src="/scripts/global.js"></script>
|- browser requests /scripts/global.js
|- page has <script src="/scripts/local.js"></script>
|- server returns global.js
|- server returns local.js
|- page has (various other tags)
|- browser requests (various other tags)
|- 
|- page loaded - document.ready fires
```

So, if `global.js` is running code before the DOM has been loaded... you're gonna run into problems. Likewise with `local.js`.

You only want to run your JS (hooking up to DOM events, etc) once the page is loaded.

If you really want to only have `$(document).ready(function(){...});` in one of your JS files, you can either:

- Hook up your own event (you'll have the exact same problem though - this is pointless)
- Include your JS files at the bottom of the page, after the DOM is loaded.

Personally, I always use `document.ready()` instead of placing scripts at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

If your going to include your external scripts inside your <head> then it is most often a good idea to put them in document readies.  If you are planning on including your scripts at the bottom of your <body> then they are unnecessary.